# difference between the below two statement for making symmetric key in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database

--symmetric key not encrypted by certification

```
create symmetric key SQLSymKey 
 with algorithm = aes_192 
    encryption by password ='uuu)) %';
```

--symmetric key encrypted by certification

```
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SQLSymKey 
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_128  
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE SelfSignedCertificate;
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: One uses a password and the other uses a certificate?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your code is non-standard SQL). Please replace the `sql` tag with a tag specific the database product you are using

Comment: Different algorithms, different encryption methods... what else is there/

Comment: yes Scsimon... that's why I am asking is there any different in respect to security.

Comment: Please read about the Encryption Hierarchy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encryption-hierarchy?view=sql-server-2017 to learn about the different ways to manage the secrets that encrypt your data.

Comment: You should also read the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327931/how-to-control-what-users-can-decrypt-sql-server-symmetric-key-encryption?rq=1) it will entirely answer your question